# Chosen Plugin Weird Graphics

Tags: jquery, jquery-chosen

Hey I am using the Chosen JQuery plugin for multiple select with search engine, But I am getting an graphic error that is really weird can someone help me?

In 100% zoom on the page it looks like this:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/BwAEg.png

With zoom at 110% looks like this:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/0ENiG.png

Can someone help me fix it for the 100% zoom?

Comment: Hey try keeping the font in the input box at 100% or even 90%--- http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_font_font-size.asp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check this out https://github.com/harvesthq/chosen/issues/1966. The first comment seemed to solve it for the OP.

So I could continue to use the same online css file, I added the following to my html file for myself (had the same problem) and it looks perfect now.

```
<style> 
.chosen-container-multi .chosen-choices li.search-field input[type="text"] {
height: 30px !important;
}</style>
```